# Как правильно обработать результат запроса?

Tags: php, sql

возник вопрос,не получается вытащить данные, как правильнее это сделать?

```
$userdata = get_user_by( 'id', $user_ID );
    $result = $wpdb->get_results(" SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `alu_user_reg` WHERE `user_group` = '" . $userdata->group . "'");

    if ($result) {
     print_r($result);
     foreach ($result as $result){
         echo $result-> COUNT(*); //так ругается
     } 
}
```

Так выглядит массив

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [COUNT(*)] => 3
        )

)
```

Спасибо!

Comment: дайте нормальное имя результату `select count(*) as cnt ...`

Comment: либо `select count(*) as cnt` и `$result->cnt` либо `$result->{"COUNT(*)"}`